# I need a shapefile of New South Wales suburbs where I can edit attribute fields

Tags: editing, census

I need a shapefile of New South Wales suburbs where I can edit attribute fields. ABS will not grant access. I wish to create a map of Tweed Shire suburbs with their percentage of population aged 65+

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: googled went to https://data.gov.au/dataset/ds-dga-91e70237-d9d1-4719-a82f-e71b811154c6/details

Comment: The ABS data can be edited if you [download it](https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/standards/australian-statistical-geography-standard-asgs-edition-3/jul2021-jun2026/access-and-downloads/digital-boundary-files), but the Geoscape data @Mapperz links to is the authoritative dataset.